# ReactJS - Swap out all the values in an array of objects in state with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I am trying to swap out all the values of an `array` of objects in state with a whole new `array` of objects. However, nothing seems to be working. I've tried the following:

```js
const list1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'item1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'item1' },
  { id: 3, name: 'item1' },
  { id: 4, name: 'item1' },
]

const list2 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'newItem1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'newItem2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'newItem3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'newItem4' },
]
```

```js
class FindTab extends Component {
  state = {
    status: 'loading',
    location: null,
    view: this.props.view,
    map: this.props.map,
    locationValues: list1,
  }
}
```

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
  locationValues: [ ...prevState.locationValues, list2 ],
}))
```

or just simpler:

```js
this.setState(locationValues: list2)
```

Neither seem to work. Is there any guidance as to how one should replace an array of objects with another array for a state property?

Comment: I should mention the structure of the objects within the array will not change, but the values and number of array objects will.

Comment: This part `this.setState(prevState => ({ locationValues: [ ...prevState.locationValues, ...list2 ] })` should *add* `list2` to the `state`. But this part `this.setState({ locationValues: list2 })` should *override* the `locationValues` inside the `state`

Answer (score 0):

You could spread the array in a new one like:

```
const locationValues = [ ...state.locationValues, ...list2 ]

this.setState({ locationValues })
```